# perforce password not masked in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, perforce

I am using cygwin on Windows and am setting up the perforce environment.

For environment variables, I set up P4USER/P4PORT/P4CONFIG.

The weird thing is that when I use p4 login, the password I typed in was not masked. I am using exactly the same setting on a linux machine and that does not give me any problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Cygwin build of p4 or the Windows build?

Comment: @Matt I am using the windows build of p4. other than this issue, other functionality of p4 seem to be working just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that I'm a bit late with this contribution, but this is the solution that I eventually figured out and appended to my .bash_profile in cygwin.  I'm posting it to save myself (and hopefully others) time in the future.

```
p4 ()
{
    _P4=`which p4`;
    if [ $1 = "login" ]; then stty -echo; fi;
    PWD=$(cygpath -wa .) "${_P4}" "$@";
    if [ $1 = "login" ]; then stty echo; fi;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect answer, but here it is FWIW.  You could use a Windows command shell to get a Perforce ticket corresponding to your password:

```
$ p4 login -p
Enter password: <type it in>
5D20E4A2F5B328EFC4908C5F9C8AC834
```

You can use the encrypted value returned by the command in lieu of your password, when using Cygwin.  Tickets do expire, however, so you might have to do this every so often.